# Spec not logging in to edit profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, activeadmin

I am using RSpec and Capybara to write some tests for editing devise user profile:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "edit profile" do
  scenario "visiting site to edit profile" do
    given_i_am_logged_in
    and_i_visit_edit_registration_page
    when_i_edit_profile
    i_should_be_redirected_to_home_page
  end
end

def given_i_am_logged_in
  @user ||= FactoryGirl.create :user
  login_as @user
end

def and_i_visit_edit_registration_page
  visit edit_user_registration_url
end

def when_i_edit_profile
  fill_in_fields
end

def fill_in_fields
  fill_in "user[name]", with: @user.name
  fill_in "user[hospital]", with: @user.hospital
  fill_in "user[email]", with: @user.email
  fill_in "user[current_password]", with: @user.password
  click_button "Update"
end

def i_should_be_redirected_to_home_page
  expect(page).to have_content("Home Page")
  expect(page).to have_link("Sign out")
end
```

The error I get is

```
Failures:

  1) edit profile visiting site to edit profile
     Failure/Error: fill_in "user[name]", with: @user.name
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "user[name]"
```

But it happens because the user is not accessing the edit_user_registration_path. It is being redirected to the login page. This is how I set up my routes file:

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }

  root to: 'home#index'
```

Can anyone see what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is shouldn't the field be user[:name]??

Comment: I don't believe so. It finds the field user[name] in other views. Funny thing is that if I put the "devise_for :users" line in the routes.rb file as the first line, the test passes, but when I try to access the activeadmin login page, it redirects me to the application login page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give any more information? Are you sure the problem is the user is being redirected? And if so, are you sure the user is being logged in correctly? If you need to, try using pry to figure out which step is failing. If the user is getting to the edit page, you can just use inspect element to make sure "user[name]" is the correct input, but I think that's right.

Comment: I balieve the problem is the redirection because I printed the page when accessing edit_user_registration_url, and the page printed was the login page, not the edit registration one. The weird thing is that if I put the "devise_for :users" line in the routes.rb file as the first line, the test passes, but when I try to access the activeadmin login page, it redirects me to the application login page.